# How do I assign factor output of a loop to a variable named after the index?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to assign the factor output of a for loop to a variable named after the index i.

My data 'dat' has five variables:
`str(dat)`

```
'data.frame':   1771 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Replicate: chr  "at20201119" "at20201119" "at20201119" "at20201119" ...
 $ Treatment: chr  "Buffer" "Buffer" "Buffer" "Buffer" ...
 $ Host     : chr  "w4k1-1" "w4k1-1" "w4k1-1" "w4k1-1" ...
 $ count    : int  113 181 72 32 168 111 77 56 17 42 ...
 $ count_mm2: num  32.08 51.38 20.44 9.08 47.69 ...
```

I want to extract all values of `Replicate` that are returned when I print all rows where `Host == (a value of interest, e.g. w4k1-1)`

First I used `split()` to split the levels of `dat$Host` into distinct dfs with `dat_list <- split(dat, as.factor(dat$Host))`

```
str(dat_list)
List of 12
 $ Col-0   :'data.frame':   352 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Replicate: chr [1:352] "at20201119" "at20201119" "at20201119" "at20201119" ...
  ..$ Treatment: chr [1:352] "Buffer" "Buffer" "Buffer" "DC3000" ...
  ..$ Host     : chr [1:352] "Col-0" "Col-0" "Col-0" "Col-0" ...
  ..$ count    : int [1:352] 41 136 58 257 47 88 324 182 174 176 ...
  ..$ count_mm2: num [1:352] 11.6 38.6 16.5 73 13.3 ...
# this is followed by 11 more df of the same structure
```

Then, and this is where I'm stuck. I try to use a for loop to get factored values of dat_list.

```
for (i in names(dat_list)){
  i <- levels(factor(dat_list$`i`$Replicate))
}
```

This returns empty character vectors for each returned value of `names(dat_list)` (so, 12 empty character vectors) and also a variable `i` with the value of the 12th element of the `names(dat_list)` output. But if I were to input

`` levels(factor(dat_list$`Col-0`$Replicate)) ``

it returns:

```
 [5] "at20201125"  "at20201203"  "at20201204"  "at20201210" 
 [9] "at20201217"  "at20201224"  "at20201231"  "W.006"      
[13] "W.007"       "W.008"       "W.010"       "W.011"      
[17] "W.014"
```

which is the desired output.

So, why won't my loop output what I want it to?

This is my first time posting a question- I've done my best to provide all the information I think is necessary- thank you very much for any help.

Comment: When using a variable, don't use `dat_list$\`\i\``, use `dat_list[[i]]`. The `$` does not work with variable values.

Comment: Any you might not even need the loop. Try `lapply(dat_list, function(x) levels(factor(x$Replicate)))`